# Can the usual Fourier series of a function be viewed as that defined with respect to an orthonormal system of functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, orthogonality, orthonormal

This query is related to how the Fourier series of a function in defined in the book Mathematical Analysis by Apostol.

Let $I$ be an interval, and let $L^2(I)$ be the set of complex-valued functions $f$ which are measurable on $I$ such that $\int_I |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty$. In subsection 11.4 of the book, the Fourier series of a function $f$ relative to an orthonormal system of functions $S = \{\varphi_0, \varphi_1, \varphi_2, \ldots\}$ on I is defined in the following way:

> Let $S = \{\varphi_0, \varphi_1, \varphi_2, \ldots\}$ be orthonormal on $I$ and assume that $f \in L^2(I)$. The notation
> $$
> f(x) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \varphi_n(x) \tag{1}\label{1}
> $$
> will mean that the numbers $c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots$ are given by the formulas:
> $$
> c_n = (f, \varphi_n) = \int_I f(x) \overline{\varphi_n(x)}\; dx \qquad (n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots). \tag{2}\label{2}
> $$
> The series in $\eqref{1}$ is called the Fourier series of $f$ relative to $S$, and the numbers $c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots$ are called the Fourier coefficients of $f$ relative to $S$.

Next, the usual *Fourier series generated by $f$* is introduced in the following way. Let $S$ be the system of trigonometric functions given by
$$
\varphi_0(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}, \quad \varphi_{2n - 1}(x) = \frac{\cos nx}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \quad \varphi_{2n}(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \qquad (n = 1, 2, \ldots). \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
Clearly, $S$ is orthonormal on any interval of length $2\pi$, and hence on $I$ when $I = [0, 2\pi]$. In subsection 11.4 of the book, for this particular $S$ and $I$, the series \eqref{1} is denoted as *the Fourier series generated by $f$*. Then, it is stated there that we can write \eqref{1} in the following form:

> $$ f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx),$$
> the coefficients being given by the following formulas:
> $$ a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \cos nt\; dt, \qquad b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \sin nt\; dt .
> $$

I don't understand how it works out. Taking the $\varphi$-functions as given in \eqref{3} and $c_n$ as in \eqref{2}, the expression in \eqref{1} is not the same as $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$. Further, in the expressions of $a_n$ and $b_n$, the $\varphi$-functions do not seem to form an orthonormal set. Is this exposition then incorrect in Apostol's book?

Also, can the expression $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$ be expressed as some form of orthonormal decomposition like in \eqref{1}?

Comment: To me it is not clear where your issue is. In which sense is the expression in (1) not the same as the Fourier expansion? Do you have an issue with the way the indices are used? And for which set of functions do you have doubts about orthonormality? The set of functions in your equation (3) do form an orthonormal system.

Comment: @Thomas I would like to relate the expression $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx)$ with (1). And in the expressions of $a_n$ and $b_n$, the $\varphi$-functions do not seem to form an orthonormal set, and they are different from the functions in (3).

Comment: You have written down the functions $\phi_n$ in (3). And they do form an orthonormal set: the constant function is orthogonal to the $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$, $\cos nx$ is orthogonal to all $\sin kx$ and also to all $\cos mx $ for $m\neq n$ - for $\sin nx$ a similar statement holds. The factors are chosen to make them length $1$ in $L^2 $. If that's not clear to you you should do the calculations. If it _is_ clear to you I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @Thomas I have indicated in my previous reply that the $\varphi$-functions used to obtain the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ by taking inner product with $f$ do not form an orthonormal set. The functions in (3) do form an orthonormal set, which can be trivially seen! I have described my queries in the last two paragraphs of the above post.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I do not see what your question is.

Comment: @Thomas it's not clear to me where you face problem in comprehending my question. I have expressed them in the last two paragraphs of the post. There is no issue with the orthonormality of the functions in (3), which You raised (not me, in the question). The problem is how they are related to the Fourier series generated by $f$, as Apostol stated.

Comment: Do you possibly have an issue with the (lack) of a normalizing factor due to the length of the interval in (1)?

Comment: Is your problem the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \varphi_n = \varphi_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\varphi_{2n-1} + \varphi_{2n})$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expressions are indeed the same. Recall that in a Hilbert space, the orthogonal projection of a vector $f$ along the subspace (line) spanned by another vector $\varphi$ is given by

$$P_\varphi(f)=\frac{\langle f,\varphi\rangle}{\langle \varphi,\varphi\rangle}\varphi,$$

which, in the case $||\varphi||=1$, reduces to $P_\varphi(f)=\langle f,\varphi \rangle\varphi$. If you have a complete system of orthonormal [resp. orthogonal] vectors $\{\varphi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ [resp] $\{\phi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ you can write

$$f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle f,\varphi_n\rangle\varphi_n \quad [\text{resp.}] \quad f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\langle f,\phi_n\rangle}{\langle \phi_n,\phi_n\rangle}\phi_n.$$

Your system of functions (3) is a complete system of orthonormal vectors, so you can write $f$ as the first sum above, if you multiply each of the $\varphi_j$ by their denominator (getting $\phi_j$), you can write $f$ as the second sum above. Finally observe that for even indexes we get sines, and for odd ones we get cosines, we might aswell re-indexing the sum above and write

$$f(x)=a_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx).$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll just detail the calculation to show in the end you get the usual form of the Fourier Series.

So you have the orthonormal basis S={  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,$\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt\pi}$,$\frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt\pi}$, ... ,$\frac{cos(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}$,$\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}$,   ....  }.

If you think back to Linear Algebra, the orthogonal projection of a vector $v$ in an orthonormal basis {$a_1, ... ,a_n$} was given by $<a_1,v>a_1 + ... + <a_n,v>a_n$.
If we follow this reasoning and switch the usual scalar product <,> to the product given by $<f(x),g(x)>=\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)dx  $, we should have the orthogonal projection of f in S is:

<f(x),$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$>  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$+ <f,$\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt\pi}$> $\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt\pi}$ + <f,$\frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt\pi}$> $\frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt\pi}$ + ... + <f,$\frac{cos(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}$> $\frac{cos(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}$ + <f,$\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}$> $\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}$ + ......  =

=$(\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dt)$$\cdot$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ + $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} <f,\frac{cos(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}> \frac{cos(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}   +$
$  <f,\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}> \frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt\pi}=$

$= \frac{\int_0^{2\pi} {f(t)}dt}{2\pi} $+   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\frac{cos(nt)} {\sqrt{\pi}} dt )\frac{cos(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi}} + (\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)\frac{sin(nt)} {\sqrt{\pi}} dt )\frac{sin(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi}}=$

$=\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}{f(t)}dt}{2\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}[\int_0^{2\pi}f(t){cos(nt)}dt]\cdot{cos(nx)} +  \frac{1}{\pi}[\int_0^{2\pi}f(t){sin(nt)}dt]\cdot{sin(nx)}.$

If you call $a_n$ the terms $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t){cos(nt)}dt$, for $n\geq0$, and $b_n$ the terms $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t){sin(nt)}dt$, for $n\geq1$, then have the orthogonal projection of f in S is:

$ \frac{a_0}{2} $+   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n {cos(nx)} +  b_n{sin(nx)}$ and this is exactly the Fourier Series of $f$ in its usual form!!!